# URL rules of python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Recently I ported my client upload code from `HTTPConnection` to `requests`. On uploading a image:

```
file_name ='/path/to/216169_1286900924tait.jpg?pt=5&ek=1'
```

The image stored on disk is really the name, and I want to upload it to remote server with same path and name, so I constructed the request like this:

```
url = 'http://host/bucket_name/%s' % (file_name)
headers = {...} # some other headers
with open(file_name, 'rb') as fd:
    data = fd.read()
    r = requests.put(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    assert(r.status_code==200)
    ....
```

But the request send to server changed to this:

```
/path/to/216169_1286900924tait.jpg
```

`requests` should encode the tail as `%3Fpt%3D5%26ek%3D1`, but it seems that `requests` do nothing on url-encode of `url`, I think it may matched the `?pt=5&ek=1` pattern to request parameters, how to make `requests` convert urls blindly without the pattern match?

### Update:

Server get the trimmed url and calculated the signature with it, and so do not match the signature I calculated with original url, so 403 returned.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "do nothing on url-encode" or what you mean by "pattern match"

Comment: The line where you're assigning something to `file_name` can't be valid Python since there are no quotation marks. Is your file really saved on disk with the query paramters in the file name? I'm not sure all file systems allow some of those characters. Your update mentions a signature, but I have no idea what that means.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a problem on the way how you construct the URL:

```
>>> payload = {'pt': 5, 'ek': '1'}
>>> r = requests.get('http://host/bucket_name/file_name', params=payload)
```

if you call the print(r.url) you should have the right form.

Answer (score 0):

Why should `requests` presume to encode the query parameters? It does not know that you don't want that part of the URL treated as the query string. Besides, the request is sent as is to the server, the query string is not omitted as you suggest. You can verify that with `nc`:

```
# run nc server
$ nc -l 1234

# then send request from Python
>>> requests.put('http://localhost:1234/path/to/216169_1286900924tait.jpg?pt=5&ek=1', data='any old thing')
```

`nc` will display the request:

```
PUT /path/to/216169_1286900924tait.jpg?pt=5&ek=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1234
Content-Length: 13
User-Agent: python-requests/2.9.1
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

any old thing
```

So it is the remote server that is (correctly according to the HTTP protocol) interpreting the `?pt=5&ek=1` part of the file name as query parameters. What else should it do?

For comparison, since I assume that it previously worked with `httplib.HTTPConnection`:

```
>>> import httplib
>>> r = httplib.HTTPConnection('localhost', 1234)
>>> r.request('PUT', '/path/to/216169_1286900924tait.jpg?pt=5&ek=1', 'hello from httplib')
```

generates this request:

```
PUT /path/to/216169_1286900924tait.jpg?pt=5&ek=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1234
Accept-Encoding: identity
Content-Length: 18

hello from httplib
```

Note that there is no difference in the way the URL is sent.

Answer (score 0):

I dig into the `requests` source code, I find the following line of code(yes, `requests` based on `urllib3`):

```
scheme, auth, host, port, path, query, fragment = urllib3.util.parse_url(url)
```

It seems like that, you should url-encode your url manually during construct your url string, for example:

```
>>> path = '''~!@#$^&*()_+|}{":?><`-=\\][\';.,'''
>>> url = 'http://host.com/bucket/%s' % path
>>> urllib3.util.parse_url(url)
>>> Url(scheme='http', auth=None, host='host.com', port=None, path='/bucket/~!@', query=None, fragment='$^&*()_+|}{":?><`-=B%7C%7D%7B%22%3A%3F%3E%3C%60-%3D%5C%5D%5B%27%3B.%2C')
```

Notice the `path` field output, *not* the same as `path`, if you encode `path`:

```
>>> path = '''~!@#$^&*()_+|}{":?><`-=\\][\';.,'''
>>> url = 'http://host.com/bucket/%s' % (urllib.quote(path, ''))
>>> print url
>>> http://host.com/bucket/%7E%21%40%23%24%25%5E%26%2A%28%29_%2B%7C%7D%7B%22%3A%3F%3E%3C%60-%3D%5C%5D%5B%27%3B.%2C
>>> urllib3.util.parse_url(url)
>>> Url(scheme='http', auth=None, host='host.com', port=None, path='/bucket/%7E%21%40%23%24%25%5E%26%2A%28%29_%2B%7C%7D%7B%22%3A%3F%3E%3C%60-%3D%5C%5D%5B%27%3B.%2C', query=None, fragment=None)
```

this what I want. But if you want to pass tome unicode characters into `path`, you do not need to encode them, they were automatically transferred into `%xx%xx` format. But url encode is a good advise for any characters you passed into URL.

Comment: The paths are different because there is a `#` which indicates that the rest of the URL is a [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). In your example the 2 URLs are actually different. I think that it's OK to `quote()` the query part of the URL, but the `#` is significant.

Comment: BTW: How did you make it work with `HTTPConnection`? Did you `quote()` the query string?